# Carga de informacion PayPal

Tags: php, mysqli, paypal

Buenas amigos en esta ocasion estoy trabajando con la API de PayPal ya tengo "todo" armado solo al momento de obtener la informacion del pago no obtengo respuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven realiza el pago pero al momento de obtener la informacion de la venta y cargar la informacion en la base de datos (MySQL) me envia error

```
 Notice: Undefined index: item_number in
 Notice: Undefined index: tx in 
 Notice: Undefined index: amt in
 Notice: Undefined index: cc in
 Notice: Undefined index: st in
```

Ahora pasemos al codigo:

```html
<form action="<?php echo $paypalURL; ?>" method="post">
        <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalID; ?>">
        
        <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        
        <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        
        <!-- Specify URLs -->
        <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://localhost/pruebas/cancel.php'>
        <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/pruebas/success.php'>
        
        <!-- Display the payment button. -->
        <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
        src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
        <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
    </form>
```

Archivo success.php:

```
//Get payment information from PayPal
$item_number = $_GET['item_number']; 
$txn_id = $_GET['tx'];
$payment_gross = $_GET['amt'];
$currency_code = $_GET['cc'];
$payment_status = $_GET['st'];
```

respuesta de la url:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El método del formulario es `POST`, entonces, deberías usar `$_POST` en vez de `$_GET`. Por otro lado, tienes que usar los índices que otorgaste a los elementos en la etiqueta `name`, usas índices como `tx,amt,` etc pero no veo `name` con esos valores. Para depuraciones haz un `var_dump($:POST);`

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano Gracias por el comentario, te cuento cambie los campos `$_GET` por `$_POST`, pase el `$_POST` por `var_dump` y y me devuelve `NULL` claro colocando los indices como lo recomiendas no afecto en lo absoluto el script que estoy corriendo esta basado en ( https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/ )

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes de `var_dump($_GET);`?

Comment: Hola @Triby obtengo el mismo resultado que con el `$_POST` te dejo un capture de `$_GET` https://prnt.sc/tup9as